# Can't take focus off NSTextField and select other NSTextFields

Tags: swift, macos, nstextfield, nspopupbutton, nsdatepicker

I am having a bit of a problem with the UI/data entry part of my macOS application. In my application I have 6 NSTextFields, 1 NSDatePicker and 1 NSPopupButton. After typing in one NSTextField (specifically the one assigned to an outlet called "itemDescriptionField" in my code) It will not allow me to select other text fields or the date picker. The code can be found at:

https://github.com/Macintoshuser2/Inventory-Manager-macOS-Swift

How can I go about resolving this?

Comment: post your code not a link

Comment: @LeoDabus added the code from ViewController.swift

Comment: In your case the code is actually irrelevant. You need to click on the arrow besides your text field and delete the number formatter child from your Cell https://www.dropbox.com/s/dzhv9zdko0xnywv/Screen%20Shot%202018-09-02%20at%2018.51.23.png?dl=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description field has a number formatter. Type numbers or remove the number formatter.